# bootstrap toggle - how to always have value to on and not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using [bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) on a test page.

The docs clearly state to prevent users from changing the value of the checkbox to add `disabled` to the element.

However, as I must submit the form, the bootstrap element cannot be disabled.

How do I prevent the user from changing the bootstrap toggle without disabling the element?

That is, when the user clicks on the bootstrap element, the bootstrap toggle will remain in the `on` state?

I have tried numerous attempts - all failed and google search does not help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_document_format_adobe" checked name="document_format" value="pdf" onclick="blur(); return false;" />
```

Here is my js code:

```
$('#id_document_format_adobe').bootstrapToggle({
  height: '30',
  width: '45',
  off: 'No',
  on: 'Yes',
  size: 'mini',
  style: 'soften',
  width: '50'
})

// set the pdf toggle switch on.
// the checkbox cannot be disabled at the element.
$('#id_document_format_adobe').bootstrapToggle('on');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I just found an obscure post.

Here is my solution.

Add the `alwaysToggleOn` to the element.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_document_format_adobe" checked name="document_format" value="pdf" onclick="blur(); return false;" onchange="alwaysToggleOn();" />
```

And in my js:

```
    function alwaysToggleOn() {
        $("#id_document_format_adobe").data('bs.toggle').on(true);
    }
```

I hope this helps someone.